# How to define MonadBaseControl for Polysemy's Sem Monad?

Tags: haskell, rabbitmq, haskell-polysemy

I wanted to use RabbitMQ with Polysemy. To consume messages from the queues I need to provide a function of type `MonadBaseControl IO m => (Message, Envelope) -> m ()`. Since I use Polysemy for all of my effects it would be great if I could use the `Sem r` Monad here as well, but I am struggling to find a way to define `MonadBaseControl IO m` for my `Sem r`. Any help is appreciated, thanks!